# not able to receive complete data from serial port

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the [link](https://github.com/AkshatPant06/Akshat-Pant/blob/master/scratch_31.py) to my github code. I want to receive serial data from com port which is of size 8196 characters..
but every time I get different data and different data size and not exactly 8196 chars..

I have tried to adjust time delays and I also included flushinput() but didn't get the complete data properly

```
import serial
import time
ser=serial.Serial(port="COM5",baudrate=57600)
ser.write(serial.to_bytes(cmd))                 
time.sleep(0.5)
data=ser.read()
time.sleep(1) 
data_left=ser.inWaiting()
data+=ser.read(data_left)
ser.flushInput()
print("Data: ",hex(int.from_bytes(data,byteorder="big")))
```

I expect to receive complete data on my console window...

Comment: did you try to change `baudrate` ?

Comment: Nit: "Bytes" not "characters". A character can occupy multiple bytes, depending on the encoding.

Comment: @furas sir i need to maintain this baudrate only..my uart is configured to this baudrate only for the entire communication

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep reading on the RX buffer until it's empty. For that you can use a loop:

```
import serial
import time
ser=serial.Serial(port="COM5",baudrate=57600, timeout=1.0)
ser.write(serial.to_bytes(cmd))                 
time.sleep(1)
data=b""
timeout = time.time() + 3.0
while ser.inWaiting() or time.time()-timeout < 0.0:   #keep reading until the RX buffer is empty and wait for 3 seconds to make sure no more data is coming
    if ser.inWaiting() > 0:
        data+=ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
        timeout = time.time() + 3.0
    else:
        print("waiting...")

ser.flushInput()
print("Data: ",hex(int.from_bytes(data,byteorder="big")))
```

The timer on the loop is intended to avoid the loop to finish when the receiver is trying to read faster than the speed at which the data is arriving.

**EDIT:** After looking a bit deeper I realized why the code above was still not working.

My (wrong) understanding was that `ser.read()` would read the number of bytes indicated by `ser.inWaiting()` but as it turns out (you just have to look at the [code](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/blob/master/serial/serialposix.py#L494)!) `ser.read()` is exactly the same as `ser.read(1)`.

As discussed, reading 1 byte at a time result in so much overhead that the RX buffer overflows. To fix that, you can just add the number of bytes available as an argument to the reading function:

```
ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
```

Apologies for the confusion on this.

Comment: All comments on my answer were deleted yesterday so I could not check your github link. Maybe you can post it again (be sure to do it on your question instead of as a comment, to avoid further trouble).

Comment: sir i am new here can you please tell me where can i attach my github code link here..i can do it in comment section but in the same question how can i do it?

Comment: i have added the link sir in my post above

Comment: I'm looking at it now

Comment: Running both scripts simultaneously (removing all sleeps) I only get 42 bytes using the default command. I don't know where those 8192 bytes are. Would you care to explain (on your question, not as comments) how you are running your code?

Comment: sir actually i am creating a testing environment in python..i need to send these commands and receive their response through UART communication..each command generates a specific response according to which these commands are programmed and shows the result..i can see my result in a software named USR TCP/IP,so these commands will receive the response based on the basis of which UART is programmed for each of these..i am getting fine responses(both on pycharm and USR software) for almost every commands as all other commands receives 1 or 2 byte of data but for A1 2D 00 00 00

Comment: for that command i am not receiving the same data as on the USR s/w..the data receiving through pycharm is unstable..its 98% accurate and lost some characters while running in pycharm..

Comment: I cannot understand how a serial-to-Ethernet converter fits into the picture. I think I won't be able to help you unless you put a bigger effort to explain your setup.

Comment: sir i am developing a testing environment.i need to code in a way like..first i have to take a file in which all the commands are written as an input..then each command will be shoot one by one and gives a specific determined response..the responses which i got needs to be matched with the actual expected responses and in the end a log file needs to be generated stating which case is pass or which case is fail..for the above command i am not getting the response which i want..i can check it on some software..so that is the problem

Comment: you're shooting these commands to a hardware serial-port-to-Ethernet adaptor, which I obviously don't have, so I cannot investigate where the missing bytes are going. I don't think the fact that any other random software succeeds in completing the reading task gives really any guarantee that your Python script would be able to do the same as it is. For instance, do you know if the software that works has any flow control mechanism? You failed to describe your setup in detail. I'm sorry but If you're too lazy to edit your question and explain what you're doing I can't help you

Comment: Last comment before this sad thread gets deleted: for certain services like Telnet (which might be at play on your setup, or might not, I have no idea...), some bytes might be understood as special commands and hence got swallowed. See, for instance [pyserial TCP/IP forwarder example](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html)

Comment: sir is there any way in python to initialize a buffer to store 4kb data in it?means is there any way by which i can set my container to store a particular amount of data only?

Comment: Python is dynamic but you can define a list of a certain size if you initialize it: `buffer=4096*[b"0xFF"]`

Comment: sir i want to elaborate my problem more to you but here there is limit of characters for every comment..where can i tell you completely?

Comment: You can click on EDIT under your question and add as much info as you need.

Comment: sir let me do one thing..let me attach a txt file on github containing all my elaboration and send it to you

Comment: this is the link above

Comment: OK, it looks a bit more clear now, I will think about it and come back if I find something useful

Comment: See updated answer, I had a wrong impression on how `ser.read()` works. I hope that fixes your problem. And accept my apologies for misleading you with my ignorance.

Comment: sir you have kept ser.inWaiting() inside ser.read() i.e. ser.read(ser.inWaiting()) this is the change you have made in the code...Right?

Comment: Yes, that should read everything stored in the RX buffer if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: i think you are somewhat correct sir!! while ser.inWaiting() or time.time()-timeout < 0.0:

Comment: plz explain me the meaning of this while statement which you have used

Comment: I have explained it above but here it is: when you read bytes 1 by 1 with `ser.read(1)` or equivalently with `ser.read()` you end up with a lot of overhead (you waste a lot of effort looping around to read just one byte). On the other hand, with `ser.read(ser.inWaiting())` you ask to read as many bytes as you have received on your buffer. Since you read more bytes on each iteration you don't need to iterate the loop so much and you reduce this undesired overhead.

Comment: nice sir..sir i tested your code..and when i use this separately..i.e..when i use only this particular command and send it to serial port(i.e. making a separate program just to test that particular command ) the i am receiving the proper output now and it is stable also..but when i am implementing that logic in the code file which i have sent you yesterday then there is the problem occur..there i am receiving unstable and incomplete data..

Comment: strange, are you sure you've implemented the change everywhere you read?

Comment: https://github.com/AkshatPant06/Akshat-Pant/blob/master/working%20file%20for%20a%20single%20cmd

Comment: sir i have shared you my code which is working on passing single command there

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea to print how many bytes you receive on every iteration around the loop. I don't see any other differences between your two files...

Comment: sir right now i don't know whether my problem will be solved..but you are a genius sir..i haven't seen a person who is having so much intent and passion to help others..for all this help i appreciate you and thank you from the bottom of my heart..but in case if i need your help again..i will disturb you again sir!!

Comment: i would be glad if you can tell in very much details about how you read..i.e. you use time.time() and add 3.0 then in while loop you are performing different operations like or operation and subtracting timeout and all..so that thing i am not getting properly how it is working..

Comment: No genius at all, just patient. I'm glad to help. What I did for the loop is only adding a small delay to make sure all data has been read before finishing the process. With `time.time()` you just capture the current time in that instant and `timeout = time.time() + 3.0` is three seconds in the future.

Comment: ohh getting it slowly now!!